# Unable to install MongoDB after following the instructions given in the document

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB and followed the instructions given in the manual but it just stays like below and never completes the installation.

[image: Installation Status]

It just be like this for hours, when I don't install MongoDB Compass it completes installation faster but when I try to open the application it's not found in my Laptop.

Please help me installing this :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the right network but I think you can install Mongo Compass separately, and then install this one (hopefully it will skip Compass installation if it sees it already exists).

Comment: yeah as suggested by @Gytis you can install compass separately. Or may be you can try Robo3t.